# Create trigger after insert

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, triggers

In my table I have besides rest following fields

```
Email 
UpperEmail
```

I should create trigger which will populate `UpperEmail` field with `Email` value transformed to upper letters. How to do this?

Comment: Did you attempt to write any code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: You could also have Computed column named UpperEmail that is just `UPPER(Email)` if you didn't want to use a trigger (replacing trigger/storage costs for on the fly calculation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of having a separate column for UpperEmail, I would suggest that you create a computed column that does this.  With a computed column, you would not need to use a trigger.

Ex:

```
Alter Table YourTableName Add UpperEmail As Upper(Email)
```

Comment: I like this idea as well, but it is a trade-off for one-time processing & additional storage Vs. processing each read of the data.

Comment: @AdamWenger, if processing time is a concern, you can persist the data in the column.  Personally, the whole questions begs the question, "Why?".  Why would you want to store the upper case version of a column, especially when the data has the potential to be large.  In most cases, a dev thinks this is necessary for searching through the data.  The reality is, SQL Server is case insensitive by default.  If you happen to be using a case sensitive collation, you could put a collate clause in the where clause, which would require less space and also perform better.

Comment: Excellent point about the persisted computed column - the rest of your points are good as well.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, have you thought about storing your e-mail addresses in a column with a case-insensitive collation? I ask because when I see someone caring about `UPPER(value)` or `LOWER(value)`, it's so they can compare in a case-insensitive manner.