# Computed column as Upper value

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As I was recommended to use computed column for problem [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819871/create-trigger-after-insert) I need advice or practical example how to create computed column `UpperEmail` which will hold `Email` value transformed to upper letters on Email insertion.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table already exists, then this should work:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD UpperEmail AS (UPPER(Email))
```